# Alter Drupals Built In Search

Tags: search, database

I'd like to change the *orderby* clause in the Drupal built-in search. I have implemented the feature in a module using *hook_query_alter*, but it doesn't seem to work. Any advice on making it work?

```
/**
* Implements hook_query_alter().
*/
function pa_search_sort_query_alter(QueryAlterableInterface $query) {

  $is_search = FALSE;

  foreach ($query->getTables() as $table) {
     if ($table['table'] == 'search_index') {
      $is_search = TRUE;
     }
   }

  if (get_class($query) !== 'PagerDefault') {
    if($is_search){
      $fields =& $query->getOrderBy();
      unset($fields['calculated_score']);
      $query->orderBy('calculated_score', 'DESC');
      }
  }
}
```